# USB-C Hub with PD and DP Alt Mode

Tags: usb, monitors, power-supply, hub, display-port

I have been looking for a USB C hub that is able to charge via PD whilst at the same time taking the video signal from the port and offering it on a separate USB C port on the hub. However after weeks of searching and buying/returning 2 hubs which looked promising (the only two I could find that had 2 USB-C ports, 1 for PD charging and the other one, which I hoped, would deliver DP Alt Mode, but unfortunately in both cases only delivered regular data transfer) I'm surprised I have not found any of these.

Does anybody know of any manufacturers that provide hubs like this?

The scenario is basically this: A laptop with only 1 USB-C port which is used for charging as well as video out. I also have an external USB-C monitor. I want to be able to use the USB-C monitor AND charge my laptop at the same time. Sounds simple enough, but alas the hardware hub for that doesn't seem to exist (it is possible, as I have hubs that let me charge my laptop whilst taking a regular HDMI output from the same port to feed video to a HDMI monitor, but this particular monitor is USB C input only).

Comment: I have the same question except I don't need PD (power delivery). Just split a USB-C into USB-C video and another output for usb data (type-a or type-c)!

Comment: There are lots of USB-C displays coming out with PD built in, if you haven't already purchased the USB-C display then you should look for this feature so that you won't even need a hub like this.